# How can I unit test IMarkupWriter's content with Tapestry 3?

Tags: java, html, unit-testing, tapestry

I'm working with an older project that is using tapestry 3, and I'd like to write tests for custom components. Is there any way to test the content that has been written to the `IMarkupWriter`?

Tapestry seems to have made the implementation classes for this interface very untestable. Calling `toString()` on it simply returns `Object.toString()`.

Creating a subclass that creates a new `toString()` is impossible since they made all of the members private in their super-classes.

Do I need to basically write an implementation of `IMarkupWriter` from scratch?

I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would tend to favor the use of [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) for mocking an interface.

However, when it comes to testing components, it's somewhat presumptuous to think you can unit test them in isolation and have any meaningful assurance that they will operate in production, since the components entirely exist to operate in concert with other components and the application as a whole: by definition, this means that meaningful tests are integration tests. I recomment using [Geb](http://gebish.org) for integration testing.